# Assigning int to nested Map<String, dynamic> resolves in Error: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Null'

Tags: dart

I get the following error

> type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Null' of 'value'

with this code snipped

```
Map<String, dynamic> test = {
  "meta": {
        "age": null,
        "gender": null,
        "height": null,
        "weight": null,
      },
  "test": "test"
};

test["meta"]["age"] = 20;
```

Why does dart thinks that `test["meta"]["age"]` has the type `Null` when I have specified that `test["meta"]`is dynamic?

How can I assign `test["meta"]["age"]` an integer value without having to further type my Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the map is here determined by what content you are putting into it. Yes, for the map `Test`, we get the correct type of the map based on provided type hints. But the inner `Map` defined by:

```dart
{
  "age": null,
  "gender": null,
  "height": null,
  "weight": null,
}
```

Does not come with any type hints. So Dart will automatically determine the type of this `Map` based on the provided values at initialization.

You can force a specific type here by doing:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> test = {
  "meta": <String, dynamic>{
        "age": null,
        "gender": null,
        "height": null,
        "weight": null,
      },
  "test": "test"
};
```